# Is comma separated value substitue for dynamically changing columns?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

Requirement: A set of data which contains decimal numbers to be inserted in db. The total number of values in this set can vary from 12 to 288.
These data are used just for calculation which will be fetched based on other parameters in other columns like:date

Solution: Should the columns be created dynamically to insert each of the values 
OR
 We can use one column which will have these values in comma separated format?

Please suggest the efficient approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should the columns be created dynamically to insert each of the values OR We can use one column which will have these values in comma separated format?

Depends on whether a set of values can be considered "atomic" from the database management perspective.

- If **yes** (all the values are *always* read from and written to the database together as a unit), then you can just go ahead and encode them into one field. A comma-separated list is one possible encoding, but using a "special" data type such as Oracle's RAW or PostgreSQL array might be even better.
- If **no** (the values do need to be accessed individually), consider the number of possible values versus the number expected to be used in a given set. If the former number is relatively small, and you can live with dynamically constructing the queries to accommodate new columns, and costs of storing NULLs in unused columns are acceptable, then you can consider dynamically adding columns.

---

But there is another alternative... If the data is "sparse" and there is a large number of applicable values, but only a small fraction will apply to a given set, then using a form of [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) might be more appropriate...

Create two tables, one for "set" and the other for "value in set" and connect them via 1:N relationship. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE SET (
    SET_ID INT PRIMARY KEY
    -- Other fields...
);

CREATE TABLE SET_VALUE (
    SET_ID INT REFERENCES SET (SET_ID),
    NAME VARCHAR(50),
    VALUE DECIMAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (SET_ID, NAME)
);
```

This way, you don't need add new columns dynamically, yet retain the ability to access the individual values (unlike comma-separated list).

Comment: The entire values are always read as a set for given criteria such as date. Could we store any sort of values(float,integer) in array of postgresql. How could we get the individual values in java if stored in array.

Comment: How long is going to be before the requirements change in such a way that you now want to retrieve some, but not all of the values based on some other criterion?  If this happens, you're going to have to do a major rewrite if you have stored them as if the set were an atomic value.

Comment: @user1709958 _"Could we store any sort of values(float,integer) in array of postgresql."_  - Yes, as long as you don't mix them in the same array (but consider [this](http://merlinmoncure.blogspot.com/2007/09/this-will-be-first-in-what-hopefully-be.html)). _" How could we get the individual values in java if stored in array."_ - I don't know, I'm sure your JDBC driver documents that and there are probably SO posts on the topic...

Comment: @user1709958 BTW, Walter raises a valid point - the database structure should reflect not just the current needs, but try to anticipate future needs as well. This is not always possible, obviously, but is something to consider...